# How do I add custom logging for which route is satisfying a request in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

I'm working on a Sinatra app that has a bunch of routes of all sorts. I'd like to add some custom logging that logs the params of the `get` or `post` call that ends up generating the response for the request. I realize I could subclass the `get`/`post` definition to wrap the block with a logging call. But I suspect there is a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sinatra's `before` hook in your controller, and print out some information contained on the `request`

```
before do
  if request.request_method == :get || request.request_method == :post
    puts request.path_info, params.inspect # check out the request variable for more info you might like to ouput
  end
end
```